# String Vector showing duplicates C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, sqlite, push-back

***Not working Code:***

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
std::vector<string> emailsfound;

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    string thefile;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        thefile = string(argv[i]);
        size_t found = thefile.find(":");
        if(found != std::string::npos)
        {
            thefile.erase(thefile.begin(), thefile.begin()+1);
            emailsfound.push_back(thefile);

            //here's the problem
            cout << emailsfound[i] << endl; //here it only couts emailsfound[0] over and over until the loop's work is done.
        }
        else
        {
        }
   }
   return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called"; //I am not printing this

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open("C:\\Users\\main.db", &db);
    if( rc )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "SELECT emails from People";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

***Working Code:***

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
std::vector<string> emailsfound;

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    string thefile;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        thefile = string(argv[i]);
        size_t found = thefile.find(":");
        if(found != std::string::npos)
        {
            thefile.erase(thefile.begin(), thefile.begin()+1);
            emailsfound.push_back(thefile);

            //Doing this makes it works great.
            printthevector();
        }
        else
        {
        }
   }
   return 0;
}

void printthevector()
{
    int sizeofthevector;
    int i = 0;
    sizeofthevector = emailsfound.size();
    while (i < sizeofthevector)
    {
    cout << emailsfound[i].c_str() << endl; //print everything / it works great
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called"; //I am not printing this

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open("C:\\Users\\main.db", &db);
    if( rc )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "SELECT emails from People";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in the first code it only counts emailsfound[0] over and over for some reason so I had to create a proper void to cout all the emails found properly.
Please explain this to me, I know I fixed it but I am not sure why the first code was not working.

Comment: `thefile.erase(thefile.begin(), thefile.begin()+1);` this might become problematic ... Did you debug already? Also would be nice to see some sample input.

Comment: Where/how is `emailsfound` declared?

Comment: thefile.erase(thefile.begin(), thefile.begin()+1) works fine.

Comment: aschepler, I already had that. I just posted the whole source maybe this will make things look better.

Comment: Okay I figured out why it wasn't printing... It's because I asking the vector to print it up in the call back function. For some reason this is happening.

Comment: I wish someone can explain to me why this is happening. I created another loop in another void and it printed the elements of emailsfound just fine but I am not exactly sure why it wasn't printing before.

Comment: First of all, `operator>>` is defined for strings, there is no surprise there.

Comment: Second, why do you `erase` the first character of `thefile`? And why are you ignoring the `found` variable? your loop most certainly does not do what you think it'll do... you should debug every step of it. And substitute the `if` for another `while`, if you want more than one email per row callback.

Comment: True, but, cout only works on constant chars and thats why I am used to add a .c_str() at the end of thr string to convert it before I cout it or else it wont work but in the code above it works without doing so for some reason.

Comment: I am erasing the first character if thefile because the first character is : and I want to get rid of it, I know there's many ways to do so but this one also works perfectly. I am not ignoring the found variable; this part of the code we're discussing works perfectly.

Comment: About the loop thing etc, well, I debugged and everything and my vector is actually being filled; all the emails are getting filled in the vector one by one which is magnificient and it's exactly want I want,but when I decide to cout << emailsfound[i].c_str() it only couts emailsfound[0] over and over until the loop finishes its work and this shouldn't be hapenning and I need your help to fix that.

Comment: Omg I just realized I dont need to c_str() because I included <string> at the top of my project and I forgot that I did that. My bad.

Comment: Okay I edited my post and now it's much better and the problem is more clear now. Please help me out understand why it was not working in the first place. Thanks in advance.